# Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment vars found but may not be correct

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, boto, ansible

We're using Ansible and aws-cli for deployment, configuration management and orchestration of our application.It's a great way to automate those process.
Unfortunately, from time to time (I can't point exactly when, but it happens after few days of working with ansible) I'm getting the following message:

> Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and
>   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment vars found but may not be correct

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 for running ansible, I'm not changing anything related to aws access-key or secret-key. I also tried to work with boto but acts the same.
The only thing that helps is restart my machine.
Any idea, what can cause this problem?

Thanks,
Effi

Comment: Please, share how did you set the credentials,  environment vars?  and more details. If you are using awscli, I suppose that you check k first the connection with  aws ec2 describe instances?

Comment: Try setting up the credentials, in the aws cli, is more stable qith the command --> aws configure

Comment: Thanks Raul, but `aws configure` didn't help :(

Comment: I setup AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as env. variables `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like amazon authentication mechanism uses client time stamp, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationTimeStamp

> **Time Stamp Requirement**
>   A valid time stamp (using either the HTTP Date header or an x-amz-date alternative) is mandatory for
>   authenticated requests. Furthermore, the client timestamp included
>   with an authenticated request must be within 15 minutes of the Amazon
>   S3 system time when the request is received.

So I used (https://askubuntu.com/questions/81293/what-is-the-command-to-update-time-and-date-from-internet):

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

in order to update my date time, and it fixed :)

Comment: I spent 7 hours trying to solve the issue until I found this. My computer had the wrong date... Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that it was running before and now it is not working. Make sure your aws cli parameters are all set and aws user has access to run ansible script. Just run date command on your machine and see whether you have correct time. If not, use time server to update your machine time and it should resolve your issue.